# SHA1 Password returns as cleartext after DB query

Tags: sql, passwords, sha1, salt

I have a SHA1 password and PasswordSalt in my aspnet_Membership table. 
but, when I run a query from the server (a Sql Query), the reader reveals
that the pass has returned as its cleartext equivalent.

I am wondering if my web.config configuration is causing this?

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider" 
                userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20"
                hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add  name="CustomMembershipProvider"
              type="Custom.Utility.CustomMembershipProvider"
              connectionStringName="MembershipDB"
              enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
              enablePasswordReset="true"
              requiresUniqueEmail="false"
              requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
              passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
              minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
              minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
              passwordFormat="Hashed"
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: OK, I got two down votes. All I am wondering is if there is some sort of ASP.NET mechanism to unencode the SHA1 hashed password in my DB upon retrieval based on the settings in my Web.config. Otherwise, I can't really explain why my hashed passwords are returning as clear-text outside of some seriously silly query oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the right settings for the membership provider (specifically `passwordFormat="hashed"`), but you also have this line:

```
type="Custom.Utility.CustomMembershipProvider"
```

Setting `passwordFormat="hashed"` only tells whichever membership provider you're using that you *want* passwords to be hashed. If you use a custom membership provider, that provider has to be coded to honour the `passwordFormat` setting.

I'm 99% sure that the reason your passwords are being stored in clear text is because that's what the `CustomMembershipProvider` is programmed to do.

Comment: I am 100% sure that the reason the pwd is clear is because the `CustomMembershipProvider` is not programmed to encrypt passwords. The tone of OP's question denotes a bit of moisture behind the ears. But he will figure it out. ;-)

Answer (score -3):

OK, I figured this one out. The answer is "yes, there is a mechanism in web.config for decrypting my SHA1 pwd automatically. Note:

> decryption="Auto"

```
<machineKey validationKey="MY Validateion Key"
            decryptionKey="My Decryption Key"
            validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" />
```

Comment: Wrong. SHA-1 cannot be "decrypted", it is a one-way hashing function. The SHA1 you see in `machineKey` relates to ViewState validation and is used to detect/prevent tampering. It has nothing to do with the membership system.

Comment: Maybe the decryption is just a hash-check. There's lots of custom-stuff in the OP's config. :)